# Documentation - how to suggest "eliminate an item"?

Tags: discussion, documentation, documentation-examples

I don't know where the "suggest delete" button is on Documentation "examples"

Comment: Downvote, click "request improvement", and pick one of the reasons like "not documentation" or "very low quality". You can add your own commentary, too, if I remember correctly. Or, just suggest the change that removes it yourself.

Comment: Ah - i didn't realize you can just "remove it" in an edit.  Well - thanks.  Perhaps that should be made clearer somewhere?

Comment: I know you can *somehow*, because I've done it before. But it takes a significant amount of work each time to figure out how. The UI is far from intuitive. There really needs to be a "delete" link, like there is on the Q&A side.

Comment: **"There really needs to be a "delete" link, like there is on the Q&A side"**  that seems both incredibly obvious and very true.  Can someone at SO just do this?  It would take 2 minutes.

Comment: "Unity3D" topic in particular offers the perfect storm of "internet nonsense generation".  (Consider the infamous "answers.unity3d.com" site.)  Because Unity is to hobbyist-programmers, what Ford was to the production line or Stalin was to death, you just an awful lot of well-meaning random nonsense on the www regarding Unity topics.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There already *is* a delete link. It's right here (you need to be in edit mode):

[image: With a red freehand circle around it.]

Comment: wait **I cannot find this**.  what do you click exactly to get to "edit mode".  I am clicking "edit" at the top of the page.

Comment: @JoeBlow you can click that then the example or you can click the edit button under the example.